# Conditional rate limiting in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I'm looking for a way to rate limit a Celery task, where we can ignore the rate limit in certain conditions.

I have a task chain in Celery that looks like this:

Task A -> Task B -> Task C

Contrived example to illustrate:

```
@app.task
def taskA(url):
   # download file from unreliable URL and return path if successful
   try:
       return download_file(url)
   except DownloadError:
       return

@app.task(rate_limit="1/m")
def taskB(file_path):
   # only expect file_path to be set 50% of time
   if file_path:
      return get_remote_api_result(file_path)
   else:
      return

@app.task
def taskC(api_result):
   if api_result:
      archive(api_result)
```

- Task B calls a remote API, which has a slow rate limit imposed by the API provider (1 request/min).
- Task B only actually calls the remote API in 50% of cases, depending on the result from Task A.
- Task B is responsible for passing the API result (or lack of) on to Task C.

The easy solution here would be to set a 1/m rate limit on Task B using Celery, but since we're only actually calling the API on every 2nd request on average, this makes the chain twice as slow as it could be.

A few options I've considered:

- Use a "gatekeeper" task.

  The chain would look like this:

  `Task A -> Task B-1 (gatekeeper)                  -> Task C
              | ^
              v |
             Task B-2 (Celery rate limited API call)`

  Task B-1 would have no rate limit, and will decide if Task B-2 should be called. Task B-2 would have our 1/m rate limit via Celery.

  - If Task B-2 is called, Task B-1 would need to wait for the result of Task B-2 before passing it to Task C.
  - If Task B-2 is not called, we can proceed to Task C immediately without impacting the rate limit counter.

  We could have Task B-1 call Task B-2 with delay() and get() synchronously to wait for the result, but this would introduce a potential deadlock.
- Ideally, we could modify the task chain on the fly by inserting Task B-2 between Task B-1 and Task C (somehow, and against much advice that this is infeasible).
- Use a custom rate limiting technique inside Task B

  Rather than rely on Celery's per-task rate limit, we could implement our own rate limit inside Task B. However, this introduces more complexity and code, so is possible, but not ideal.

I'm keen to hear any thoughts about which strategy might be best - or is there a simpler solution altogether?

Comment: Is there a reason instead of doing `return download_file(url)` in taskA you cant do `file_ = download_file(url)` then `chain(taskB.s(file_), taskC.s()).delay()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't go into detail previously, but the A->B->C chain is dynamically calculated by another process entirely, based on a task dependency graph. As it stands, a subtask in the chain doesn't know what tasks will be launched after it, and so Task A wouldn't be in a position to launch the Task B -> Task C chain.